# How to pivot pandas dataframe according to multiple columns with new names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe like this which is around 10million rows

```
Date       AirPressure SoilMoisture Temperature Humidity WindSpeed WindDirection Source
2010-01-01 xxx.        xxx          xxx         xxx.     xxx.      xxx.          Location1
2010-01-02 xxx.        xxx          xxx         xxx.     xxx.      xxx.          Location1
2010-01-03 xxx.        xxx          xxx         xxx.     xxx.      xxx.          Location1
....
2010-01-01 xxx.        xxx          xxx         xxx.     xxx.      xxx.          Location2
...
2020-10-10 xxx.        xxx          xxx         xxx.     xxx.      xxx.          Location8595
```

I need to pivot it so that it looks like this,

```
Date       AirPressure-Location1 SoilMoisture-Location1.....WindDirection-Location8595
2010-01-01 xxx.                  xxx                        xxx
......
2020-10-10 xxx.                  xxx                        xxx
```

I tried `frame = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Source')`,

But I am left with

```
                       AirPressure...                            WindDirection    
Date       Location1   Location2.......Location8593 Location8594 Location8595
2010-01-01 xxx.        xxx             xxx          xxx.         xxx.                
2010-01-02 xxx.        xxx             xxx          xxx.         xxx.              
2010-01-03 xxx.        xxx             xxx          xxx.         xxx.               
....
2010-01-01 xxx.        xxx             xxx          xxx.         xxx.              
...
2020-10-10 xxx.        xxx             xxx          xxx.         xxx.
```

How can I fix my code?